# Mongo Aggregation: count distinct accounts with nested array with and without a value match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this:

```
{ account: 2, {payments: [{flag: false, amt: 100},{flag: false, amt: 100}]},
{ account: 3, {payments: [{flag: false, amt: 100},{flag: false, amt: 100}]},
{ account: 4, {payments: [{flag: true, amt: 50},{flag: false, amt: 100}]}
```

I would like to aggregate and sum amt and count account with at least 1 true

```
{"true": { "count":2, "sum_amt": 150}},
{"false": { "count": 2, "sum_amt": 0}}
```

*Note: I am counting the distinct accounts with at least 1 true vs accounts with all false.

I have tried

```
[
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$remits"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 1,
      account: true,
      remits: {
        flag: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        flag: "$payments.flag"
      },
      uniqueCount: {
        $addToSet: "$account"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "flag": 1,
      cnt: {
        $size: "$uniqueCount"
      }
    }
  },
  {}
]
```

but I think I need to project a field to account level if there is one true for any account with at least 1 true .. I can not match since I need to count the ones with no true.

Comment: ```[{$unwind: {
  path: "$remits"
}}, {$project: {
  "_id":1, account:true, remits : { flag: true }
}}, {$group: {_id: {flag: "$payments.flag"}, 
uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$account"}}}, {$project: {"flag":1, cnt:{$size:"$uniqueCount"}}}, {}]```.   ..unfortunately,  I am counting the account in both the false and true buckets

Comment: Post please valid JSON for input sample + valid expected value since `true: count:2` is not valid

Comment: fixed the expected output thanks

Comment: JSON keys must be strings, please fix them too.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly then you are looking to filter documents with atleast one true flag and do some group by.

lets say you have below sample documents:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e9d17ca9db790488c44e8f6"},"account":"2","payments":[{"flag":true,"amt":{"$numberInt":"100"}},{"flag":false,"amt":{"$numberInt":"100"}}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e9d1f6a9db790488c44e8f9"},"account":"3","payments":[{"flag":false,"amt":{"$numberInt":"100"}},{"flag":false,"amt":{"$numberInt":"100"}}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5e9d1f769db790488c44e8fa"},"account":"4","payments":[{"flag":true,"amt":{"$numberInt":"50"}},{"flag":false,"amt":{"$numberInt":"100"}}]}
```

and we use below pipeline query:

```
[{$match: {
  'payments.flag': true 
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$payments"
}}, {$group: {
  _id:{$concat: [ "Account:",'$account','-',{$toString:'$payments.flag'}]},
  count: {
   $sum: 1
  },
  amount:
  {$sum:'$payments.amt'}
}}]
```

Output would be like :

```
_id:"Account:4-false"
count:1
amount:100

_id:"Account:2-false"
count:1
amount:100
```

Comment: No filtering.   I want to Group by, count distinct and sum by a projection that is True if the account has a true flag and false if the account has no true flags.   Note the expected results in the question.  Thanks